# how to get 1st array value

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

```
{
  "status": "true",
  "data": [
    {
      "giid": "91",
      "gid": "26",
      "name": "gallery/image/7475068.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": ""
    },
    {
      "giid": "92",
      "gid": "25",
      "name": "gallery/image/8704185.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": ""
    },
    {
      "giid": "93",
      "gid": "25",
      "name": "gallery/image/3639377.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": ""
    },
    {
      "giid": "94",
      "gid": "25",
      "name": "gallery/image/5589478.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": ""
    },
    {
      "giid": "95",
      "gid": "25",
      "name": "gallery/image/3503162.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": ""
    }]}
```

get only first value in my list view how its possible?

my code :-

```
try {
                        JSONArray jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                            System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                            JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(i);

                            Beans_News info = new Beans_News();

                            info.setDate(object1.getString("giid"));
                            info.setNews(object1.getString("name"));
                            info.setNewsid(object1.getString("gid"));
                            info.setStatus(object1.getString("type"));

                            array_bean.add(info);
                            lvls.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter_classwork());
                            pDialog.hide();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
```

i want only first value in my list please help me

Comment: #Invalid JSON .Rectify first

Comment: If you want to access only first then access it only for 0 index

Comment: i have edited your json format

Comment: doing perfect in the above code, do not use for iterator simple get the first jsonarray element using array index=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
//remove for loop if you only need single data
//for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
//if you need first value set 0 in index
   JSONObject object1 = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
info.setDate(object1.getString("giid"));
info.setNews(object1.getString("name"));
info.setNewsid(object1.getString("gid"));
info.setStatus(object1.getString("type"));
```

try this hope it helps

Comment: which single value you want @niravshah? you want "giid": "91",
      "gid": "26",
      "name": "gallery/image/7475068.png",
      "type": "0",
      "singer": "" this values?

Comment: please mark this as a correct answer if this helps you @niravshah So others getting help from this if you mark this as correct answer. Happy to help you :) :) :)

Comment: @niravshah please mark this answer as correct if this helps you

Comment: if i want the only last record then...?

Comment: then use JSONObject object1 = jArray.getJSONObject(jArray.length() - 1); hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you send response like:

```
  res.send({'status':'true', 'data': data})
```

or

```
res.json({'status':'true', 'data': data})
```

and this data is a array  then you can get 1st element like

```
obj = response;
let arr= obj.data;
if(arr.length>0) firstElement = arr[0]
else //whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Made Changes here

```
 JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(0);
```

Use 0 index

Answer (score 0):

Just set **.getJSONObject(0);**

```
JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(0); // Set 0 for First Value
Beans_News info = new Beans_News();
info.setDate(object1.getString("giid"));
info.setNews(object1.getString("name"));
info.setNewsid(object1.getString("gid"));
info.setStatus(object1.getString("type"));
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
Beans_News info = new Beans_News();
info.setDate(jsonObject.getString("giid"));
info.setNews(jsonObject.getString("name"));
info.setNewsid(jsonObject.getString("gid"));
info.setStatus(jsonObject.getString("type"));
```

this is the simplest code you can try to achieve your task.